# How extract correct value from Json object (Google Places Geocoder)

Tags: jquery, json

Sorry to all, I need help for this.

This is my object (I cannot copy&&paste from firebug)

[image]

Same from here (paragraph "Json Output formats") : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "address_components": [
                {
                    "long_name": "1600",
                    "short_name": "1600",
                    "types": ["street_number"]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "Amphitheatre Pkwy",
                    "short_name": "Amphitheatre Pkwy",
                    "types": ["route"]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "Mountain View",
                    "short_name": "Mountain View",
                    "types": ["locality", "political"]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "Santa Clara",
                    "short_name": "Santa Clara",
                    "types": ["administrative_area_level_2", "political"]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "California",
                    "short_name": "CA",
                    "types": ["administrative_area_level_1", "political"]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "United States",
                    "short_name": "US",
                    "types": ["country", "political"]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "94043",
                    "short_name": "94043",
                    "types": ["postal_code"]
                }
            ],
            "formatted_address": "1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA",
            "geometry": {
                "location": {
                    "lat": 37.42291810,
                    "lng": -122.08542120
                },
                "location_type": "ROOFTOP",
                "viewport": {
                    "northeast": {
                        "lat": 37.42426708029149,
                        "lng": -122.0840722197085
                    },
                    "southwest": {
                        "lat": 37.42156911970850,
                        "lng": -122.0867701802915
                    }
                }
            },
            "types": ["street_address"]
        }
    ],
    "status": "OK"
}
```

I need to iterate in address_components and extract the administrative_area_level_2, putting in a variable, if administrative_area_level_3 is NOT present (not all address have level 3 and in that case, in Italy, you can use the level 2).

So, I'm trying this:

```
$.each(result.address_components, function(index, types) {
    //FROM HERE PSEUDO CODE... PLEASE HELP
    if (types.type[0]['administrative_area_level_3'] == NULL)
    {
        var administrative_area_level_3 = types.type['administrative_area_level_2'];
    }
});
```

So, with my image, administrative area level 3 and 2 will have same value (Rome).

Please, could you help me? Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying and trying, this is the "solution":

```
        var area2 = null;
        var area3 = null;
        $.each(result.address_components, function(index, types){
            if (types.types[0]=='administrative_area_level_2')
            {
                area2 = types.long_name;
            }
            if (types.types[0]=='administrative_area_level_3')
            {
                area3 = types.long_name;
            }
        });
        if (area3==null)
        {
            area3 = area2;
            $('input[name=administrative_area_level_3]').val(area3);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
if (types.type[0]['administrative_area_level_3']==NULL)
                 -------------------------------------^
```

instead of

```
if (types.type[0]['administrative_area_level_3'])==NULL
```